# How to investigate and resolve Throttling Time issue in Azure Data Lake Analytics?

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

I got following warning on one of my successful ADLA job:

```
Throttling Time: The job exhibited throttling which may have impacted performance.
```

In the job, I am reading data from a table, doing some processing and writing results in two different tables along with updating input table. Here is some information about distribution scheme(just in case it helps):

Input/Output Table: Distributed by Round Robin with 250 distributions (Each partition contains around 215 GB data)

Output Table 1: Distributed by Round Robin with 250 distributions (Each partition contains around 215 GB data)

Output Table 2: Distributed by Round Robin with 10 distributions (Each partition contains around 4 GB data)

I need help in understanding and analyzing U-SQL job for throttling issue and how to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

**Old answer**

Right now there is not much you can do with this diagnostic, except contacting support with the job link and ask if the bandwidth can be increased for your account for this job.

**Addendum**

Since this error message was noisy and confusing, it got removed for now until we can provide a more actionable error message.